# avoid mismatch between server side and client side result

Tags: javascript, php, coding-style

I use PHP and Javascript. In my website some results are processed server side some client side.

Using javascript only, prevents your website from being crawled correctly by search engines and using PHP only prevents correct real time response.

The problem is how to grantee both js functions and PHP functions give the same result? for example suppose there is a function which gives relative time:

**JS:**

```
function relative_time(timestamp)
{
   ...
}
```

**PHP:**

```
function relative_time($timestamp)
{
   ...
}
```

Keeping both functions matched with each other is not easy since I want to edit both. For example if both give us:

```
one year ago
```

And I change PHP only, to give me:

```
a year ago
```

Then JS is not updated too. Is there any standard way to ensure both will act in the same way?

---

unfortunately js function cannot be called on server side.

Comment: sound like [an XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)

Comment: may you clarify how my question is XY?

Comment: Can this help you anyhow? https://code.google.com/p/php-to-js/

Answer (score 0):

If there is some complicated logic, you should implement it server-side and just pull the results via AJAX. That way you only need to maintain the PHP code and provide a kind of AJAX API for access via JS.

Comment: true. but i'm thinking about reducing server traffic.

Answer (score 0):

I think you just need to make a decision where it is to be done, because if they do vary which is to be dominant ? (that's the one that should be doing it)
Also, how are you saving server load by doing it in both locations ?

Avoid this by making a decision for which code is to do it, failing that, Put a note in you code at both locations reminding yourself to update both locations ?

Comment: the problem is that one code must be written in two languages which looks redundant. server and client side validation is another example of similar codes in two languages. how can i avoid that?

Comment: Good point - comments in code so I guess.
[ Added ... but I guess that's a different reason ... nothing to do with saving server resources ]